# Slicing a MultiIndex has some values not restricted within bound

Tags: pandas

I'm not sure what is the problem here.

```
df = pd.read_csv('http://astro1.panet.utoledo.edu/~terencezl/static/20160421/df.csv', index_col=['T', 'mu'])
sls = pd.IndexSlice
df.loc[sls[:, -0.25:0.25], :]
```

The second level of the resulting dataframe's index still has values out of bound.

```
                              x
T           mu
290.000000  -0.500234 -1.000000
            -0.490234 -1.000000
            -0.480234 -1.000000
            -0.470234 -1.000000
            ...
            -0.220234 -1.000000
            -0.210234 -1.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

float index is not recommended

try to reset index

```
(df.reset_index()
   .query('-0.25<mu<0.25')
)
```

Comment: But it looks like such a simple operation.

Comment: FYI, pandas indexing and selecting data
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html

Comment: I fail to see any explanation. I went through the official docs in the past a few times.

Comment: when you reset_index, the index mu becomes a column, then you can filter out what you need.

you can use between as well, df = df.reset_index(), df[df.mu.between(-0.25,0.25)],  which is 2x faster. however, it will be deprecated in a near future.

Comment: it maybe a bug when you slice a float multi-index

Comment: Thanks. Also query works without resetting the index.